# Loop for differing inputs for functions then stops at certain value

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, input, while-loop

Hi I am trying to write some VBA code so that 1 piece of my input data "G" changes in size that the corresponding equations further in my excel file (4 cells) iterate through using G until reaching a certain number... say 1. The G that results in 1 is then given.

So far my code looks something like:

```
Sub For_loop()
Dim x As Single

    For x = 1 To 10 Step 0.1
        ...
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question its kind of unclear. Is "G" supposed to be the return value and if it returns 1 you want to know what the value of the iterator was at that time?

Answer (score 1):

You run into a [precision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_precision_in_Microsoft_Excel) if you do this

```
Sub For_loop()
    Dim x As Single

    For x = 1 To 10 Step 0.1
        Debug.Print x
    Next x
End Sub
```

the output will be the following:

```
 1 
 1,1 
 1,2 
 1,3 
 1,4 
 1,5 
 1,6 
 1,7 
 1,8 
 1,9 
 2 
 2,1 
 2,2 
 2,3 
 2,4 
 2,5 
 2,6 
 2,7 
 2,799999 
 2,899999 
 2,999999 
 3,099999 
 3,199999 
 3,299999 
 3,399999 
 3,499999 
 3,599999 
 3,699999 
 3,799999 
 3,899998 
 3,999998 
 4,099998 
 4,199998
 …
```

This is not a bug but because computers calculate numeric but not absolute (like any calculator does too). There is some kind of precision but the result is always very near to the truth but not exatcly.

Keep your loop increasing full integers instead of decimals and devide `x` by `10`

```
Sub For_loop2()
    Dim x As Long

    For x = 10 To 100 Step 1
        Debug.Print x / 10
    Next x
End Sub
```

to get a more precise result

```
 1 
 1,1 
 1,2 
 1,3 
 1,4 
 1,5 
 1,6 
 1,7 
 1,8 
 1,9 
 2 
 2,1 
 2,2 
 2,3 
 2,4 
 2,5 
 2,6 
 2,7 
 2,8 
 2,9 
 3 
 3,1 
 3,2 
 3,3 
 3,4 
 3,5 
 3,6 
 3,7 
 3,8 
 3,9 
 4 
 4,1 
 4,2 
 …
```

More about this: [Understanding Floating Point Precision, aka “Why does Excel Give Me Seemingly Wrong Answers?”](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/)

Comment: ok great thanks! this varies it properly but how do i select this variation to halt when an equation this input affects hits a certain number (say 1). and report this number back to me

Comment: Which equation? Please give a concrete example with example data. You can edit it into your original question. I think you probably should google for excel solver: [Define and solve a problem by using Solver](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040) looks like you could use that instead of writing something on your own.

Comment: I have a large excel file with lots of data and some functions that give output depending on that data. Essentially I want to vary 1 of the inputs like you did above until the corresponding output of one of those functions hit the number 1. then when it hits 1 to tell me what the input data limit was to make it 1. unfortunately sharing the equations would be difficult without sending my whole document.

Comment: Again, please edit your original question and give at last one exact example (see [mcve]) It is not possible to answer that without knowing what exactly you are doing. The information you gave is a way to less. Also please check if the Solves (link above) does solve your issue. You can copy the equations into your question too. I guess the Solver is the right tool for you.